# How do I inject a local stateless session bean into a JAX-RS resource using CDI?

Tags: glassfish, jersey, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I have an `.ear` file with the standard `lib` directory.

I have a `.jar` file in that `lib` directory.  It contains `UserInfoManager`, which is an interface.  It contains (for these purposes) no other classes.  It also contains a `META-INF/beans.xml` file.

I have another `.jar` file in that `lib` directory.  It contains a class named `UserInfoResource` that is a JAX-RS resource class.  That class has the following inside it:

```
@Inject
private UserInfoManager userManager;
```

Next, I have an EJB `.jar` file at the root of the `.ear` file.  It contains a class named `UserManagerBean` that implements the `UserInfoManager` interface.  This class is annotated with `@Stateless` and basically nothing else (thus making it a local stateless session bean exposed via its local business interface (`UserInfoManager`).  This `.jar` file also has a `META-INF/beans.xml` file.

Next, I have a `.war` file with an `Application` class in it and nothing else.  This serves as the "mounting point" for any and all JAX-RS resources discovered at deployment time present in the `lib` directory.  I do not declare this Java EE 6 module as a CDI bean archive since it contains no beans.

This spec-compliant arrangement fails at deployment time.  Weld (the CDI implementation in GlassFish 3.1.2) claims that the injection point detailed above cannot be satisfied, as there are no known implementations of `UserInfoManager` available to it.

When that injection point is annotated with `@EJB` instead, everything works fine.

How do I get CDI to inject a local stateless session bean reference into a JAX-RS resource that is present on the classpath?

**Update:** Because no matter how I look at this it seems like a specification violation, I have [filed a bug with a testcase attached](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793).  I encourage readers to take a look and see if they can get it to work.

**Update:** The workaround is to make sure that your JAX-RS classes are *not* bean archives, but *are* annotated with `@ManagedBean`.  In addition, the {{.war}} file that serves as their mount point must be a bean archive (must have a {{WEB-INF/beans.xml}} file).  Some combination of these requirements is a CDI specification violation.  The following bug tracks these issues: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793

Comment: Is UserInfoResource declared @RequestScoped?

Comment: Hello; no; I have not added any CDI annotations to `UserInfoResource`.

Comment: I made the suggested change; there was no difference in the outcome.

Comment: Do you have an application.xml defined in your ear?  You mention locations of jar files and war files, but not how they're defined in the ear's application.xml.

Comment: Yes, I do (it is auto-generated by Maven at version 6).  Without CDI injection, the JAX-RS resource and EJB work fine.  I've filed a bug complete with test case here: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793 Please feel free to take a look.

Comment: Just tested the app you attached to the GF bug and was able to get it deploy and do what you need - see my answer below. But it may still be a valid bug, so left it open.

Comment: Thanks, Martin; I made the changes you suggested, and still encounter the error.  I have uploaded a new version of the app there so you can see if it (still) works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey does not treat Resources as managed beans unless there is an explicit scope/@ManagedBean annotation attached to it. So, you need to annotate your resource with @ManagedBean or @RequestScoped for the injection to work.

Seems the problem occurs only if beans.xml is included in the resource jar file. When I remove it and attach @ManagedBean annotation to the resource class (instead of @RequestScoped, since @RequestScoped does not work if no beans.xml is present) it works. I am not a CDI expert, so not sure if this is as designed or a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the effort.  While with your changes I can get the application to deploy, any invocation of the actual resource still results in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Forgot to note you need to add beans.xml to the WEB-INF folder of your war. With that the injection should work as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Martin.  I have summarized the various GlassFish bugs and specification interpretation issues over at the GlassFish issue page: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793?focusedCommentId=341270&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_341270

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since it got me working; however for other readers please see the relevant bug: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793  There are _many_ implications for JAX-RS and CDI portability contained in it.

Comment: I believe JAX-RS classes on JBoss AS7.1.0 have the same issue. The EE6 tutorial (which may be incorrect) says a JAX-RS class should be annotated with `@RequestScoped` for it to be CDI enabled, but this doesn't work on AS7. The JAX-RS class has to be annotated with `@ManagedBean` or made a session bean itself (`@Stateless`) and then `@EJB` injections work as expected.